# Subquery to by bypass where clause

Tags: mysql

Good morning, mysql query which displays cases that have a date field completed & a total row amount, I want calculate this against the total cases but unsure if I can do all this inside one query. For example the current query outputs

```
Aug Sep Nov Total
10  20  20  50
```

The code for that being

```
     SELECT * from(
     Select Count(b.CaseID) As TotDB 
     from tblcontacts a 
     Inner Join  tblcases b 
     On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo)a
CROSS JOIN
    (Select
  Sum(Month(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 8) As Aug,
  Sum(Month(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 9) As Sep,
  Sum(Month(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 10) As Oct,
  Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
  ROUND (100*Count(b.CaseID)/Count(b.CaseID),2) As Conversion
From
  tblcontacts a Inner Join
  tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo
Where
  b.StatusSubmittedDate > '2012 - 01 - 01'
Group By
  a.ContactFullName With Rollup
Having
  Sum(b.CaseCommission) > 0.01)b
```

What I need to it output is the below so I added the TotDB line above to see if that would help, it didn't. What I need to find out is can I have a column in this query that bypasses the where/having clause to display all records

```
Aug Sep Nov Tot TotDB %Converted
10  20  20  50  100   50%
```

Thanks

Comment: What you nedd exactly ? Will You explain more?

Comment: Currently the query uses where & having to filter the data to only records with data after 2012-01-01 & > 0.01. I need to TotDB column to bypass this and display a count of all records in DB?

Comment: ` b.StatusSubmittedDate > 2012 - 01 - 01` does that even work? Aren't you doing ` b.StatusSubmittedDate > 2010` there? try ` b.StatusSubmittedDate > '2012-01-01'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you should do like this:

```
select Aug,Sep, Nov, Tot,TotDB,(Tot/TotDB*1.0)*100 as '%Converted' 
 from 
(SELECT * from(
     Select Count(b.CaseDate) As TotDB 
     from tblcontacts a 
     Inner Join  tblcases b 
     On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo)a
CROSS JOIN
    (select  
      Sum(Month(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 9) As Sep,
      Sum(Month(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 10) As Oct,
      Sum(Month(b.StatusSubmittedDate) = 11) As Nov,
      Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
    From tblcontacts a 
    Inner Join tblcases b 
    On a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo
    Where
      b.StatusSubmittedDate > '2012-01-01'
    Group By
      a.ContactFullName With Rollup
    Having
      Sum(b.CaseCommission) > 0.01)b)c
```

Comment: @Konerak, thanks yes, it did work like that but I have now added the '2012-01-01'.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind suggestion, that does indeed add another column with total records in that table, I have tried to then use that column to calculate % between total but it just returns the same value, I updated original code above to show. The calc is referencing the same field, I need it to  calc field from 1 & 2nd query? Does that make sense..

Comment: Thanks again, really helpful, that now outputs Tot 10 | TotDB 475 | %Converted 10. The %Converted calc should return 2% in that example but it appears to return the tot column value? The Tot column is cases that have actually completed, the TotDB column is the entire count of cases table so I am trying to get % of casse that have completed? Many thanks again.

Comment: That's brilliant Joe exactly what I needed, thank you for your time. To format the % field I changed the end code slightly to Round((c.Total / c.TotDB * 1.0), 4) * 100 As 'Conversion'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in one simple query.

The right way to do that, is to do a second query, without the where clause. Really.

If you MUST do this in one query, atleast use a union:

```
/* old query */
SELECT a,b,c from t1,t2,t3 where d=e group by a having b>f
UNION
select 'total',COUNT(*),NULL /*need the same amount of rows*/
from t1,t2,t3
```

And have your clientside treat the row where `a='total'` differently. But that's a hack. I would advise you to use two queries.